How to resolve user-specific installation path issues with Electron auto-updates?
I am developing an Electron application with the following setup:
Electron Version: 29.3.0
Electron-Builder Version: 24.13.3
Electron-Updater Version: 6.2.1
The application is working as expected, including the differential auto-update functionality. However, I am encountering an issue related to the user-specific paths used during updates.
Issue Description: The application is initially installed using a temporary admin account. The installer places the update-related files in the following path:C:\Users\tempadmin\AppData\Local\crewworks-onboard-app-updater
However, when a different user runs the application, Electron attempts to download updates to this path:C:\Users[CurrentUser]\AppData\Roaming\crewworks-onboard-app
Since the updates are being downloaded under the CurrentUser directory, the application fails to locate the installer, which was originally placed in the tempadmin path during installation.
Questions:
How can I configure Electron-Updater to use a consistent installation path across different users?
Is there a recommended approach for managing application updates when the installation is performed under an admin account but used by other non-admin users?
Any guidance on configuring the path settings or handling user-specific directories for Electron updates would be greatly appreciated.
i manually placed the insatller in the curentuser and i can see the differential updates is downloaded and its worked as exepected and by using a single user that time also working.But by default its not working when multiple user using.

Try to install in System level
